# What is the proper way to handle the interaction of subclasses that all have different operations?

Tags: c++, oop

Thanks for taking the time too look at my question. It's pretty general but I can't seem to find very much information on it. I've looked at similar questions but none of the examples seem to be this convoluted.

In C++ I am looking for the proper way that sub-classes should interact given that each pair has a different set of operations.

Lets say I have the following classes with sub-classes.

```
      Vehicle                                          Tires
         |                                               |
      Motorcycle                                       / | \
       /  |  \                                   Snow Seasonal Summer 
  Honda Suzuki Yamaha
```

Let's say I have a function for each type (Honda, Suzuki, Yamaha) called `Performance(Tires tires)` that does certain operations based on the type of tires. I was wondering what would be the "best practices" way to implement this in a general way. The issue that I am running into is that each pair has different operations that need to be done, e.g. `Honda.Performance(snowTires)` is different from `Honda.Performance(seasonalTires)` and it is also different from `Suzuki.Performance(snowTires)`. My issue is that implementing something like the following seems like a poor solution because it would also have to be implemented for the other subclasses of Motorcycle.

```
void Honda::Performance(Tires tires)
{
if(tires are Snow)
{
  //snow ops
}
elseif(tires are seasonal)
{
   //seasonal ops
}
else
{
   //summer ops
}
}
```

Any constructive suggestions or advice are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: [_Decorator_ or _Strategy_ design patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)? Or both.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I will take a look at that thanks.

Comment: fwiw, not everything must be a member function. `Suzuki.Performance(snowTires)` can be `performance(Suzuki,SnowTires)`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 in that case wouldn't I still need to do the if/case method for each pair?

Comment: if every combination is different you need to implement every combination, the question is just how to organise them. Instead of long if/else chains you would have one overload for each combination

Comment: Useful related reading: [What is an example of the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle). TL;DR version: if you have subclasses that cannot or should not follow the same interface, you're in for some pain.

Comment: @user4581301 I will check that out thanks.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think the Strategy design pattern may be a good option for my application. I think I will give it a go and see where that takes me. Thanks!

Comment: Are you really passing in your Tires by value? Because, they will get sliced.

Comment: @jxh This was just a simple example based on my situation to understand the best organization.

Comment: @sokato Trying to use the given example as a basis for testing doesn't work. A reference or a pointer is needed for the dynamic binding to be valid.

Comment: @jxh Using a reference or pointer is fine. The example was just to present the idea.

Comment: What is the root of the difference in calculating performance of `snowTires`  vs `seasonalTires`?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk The actual code is a thermodynamic/chemical kinetics code that calculates properties of different types of chemical reactors e.g., constant volume, constant pressure, etc. So, there are differences in the equations of each. I just put this example together to get the idea across. So, the two classes are not defined the only constraint is that they require different equations lets say.